How To Reset AnchorUtils.loadEnv() Wrong Keypath From Other Projects
I have in the past been able to compile and deploy these switchboard example projects to devnet: https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/sb-on-demand-examples/tree/main/sb-randomness-on-demand
Now when I try to clone this project, I can build it with anchor build, use the correct keys with anchor keys sync, build again, and deploy the program and idl to devnet. It does create the keyfile on the first build at: target/deploy/sb_randomness-keypair.json 
When I try to run the pnpm start after installing it gives me an error that it can't find the keyfile:
    at /Users/jim/projects/sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/node_modules/.pnpm/@switchboard-xyz+on-demand@1.2.51_bufferutil@4.0.8_fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder@1.0.22_utf-8-validate@5.0.10/node_modules/@switchboard-xyz/on-demand/dist/cjs/anchor-utils/AnchorUtils.js:31:71 {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './target/deploy/sb_randomness-keypair.json'
}

Is there some reason my anchor would be "corrupted" from working on other projects? Can I clean it out somehow and make this work again? It seems like there were no changes to this repo since I had it working so I'm pretty sure the error is just my setup and whatever the value it's getting for sb.AnchorUtils.loadEnv()...

You are most likely working in the wrong directory.
Install the script dependencies in the root. sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand
pnpm install 

change directory into the anchor program and build the program sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand/sb-randomness
anchor build

Go back to previous directory and run the start script sb-on-demand-examples/sb-randomness-on-demand
pnpm start


Yep, this is exactly what I'm doing. Seeing the error, "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './target/deploy/sb_randomness-keypair.json' when running pnpm start from the sb-randomness-on-demand folder.
